# How do I manually utilize a source map for an IE8 error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, source-maps

IE8 Reports that there is an error on line 1, character 3550. Since IE8 doesn't support source maps, how can I use my sourcemap to manually lookup the location of the error in the pre-uglified source?

Comment: You may find some success in the various [Source Map Visualization tools](https://github.com/ryanseddon/source-map/wiki/Source-maps%3A-languages,-tools-and-other-info#tools-that-consume-source-maps) online.